# Object.getNotifier() part of Polymer webcomponents polyfill?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polyfills, object.observe

I have a Polymer app that runs in Chrome, but in Firefox and Safari I get the error
`TypeError: Object.getNotifier is not a function`

I included the webcomponents.min.js polyfill library (which includes observe-js), which I thought polyfilled this functionality.  Is there something I'm missing?

We're using Polymer v0.5.5

Thanks!

Comment: It will be hard for someone to assist from this, please debug and share the part of the code failing to ask a more specific question.